# same width columns in CSS grid - IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I have a grid with 3 columns. The problem is that the 3rd column is wider than the other two columns. 
Neither

> grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(33.33%, 1fr));

nor

> grid-auto-columns: 33%;

work, because auto-fit and grid-auto-columns aren't supported in IE11.

Is there an alternative way to achieve that in IE11? 
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative way, you could try to use Bootstrap to achieve the same layout, code as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]